# How can I upload a file to S3 without creating a temporary local file?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Is there any feasible way to upload a file which is generated dynamically to amazon s3 directly without first create a local file and then upload to the s3 server? I use Python.

Comment: The answers below explain two ways to do this. But if you ever run into an API that can only take files, you might want to look at `tempfile.TemporaryFile`; with the right parameters, you get a file-like object, as close to not being a real file as possible. (On POSIX, this means it has no directory entry and isn't backed to disk unless necessary; on Windows it's actually a wrapper object around a file object that does exist in the temp directory until you close it, which isn't always good enough, so you may have to PyWin32 `CreateFile` and do some more complicated code to get what you want).

Comment: At the moment boto does not have functionality for this. The `Key.open_write()` method is not yet implemented. Once it is you will have the answer. `set_contents_from_stream()` allegedly can read from a stream object but it actually expect a file... I do not know if it can be used somehow...

Answer (score 26):

Here is an example downloading an image (using requests library) and uploading it to s3, without writing to a local file:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
import requests

#setup the bucket
c = boto.connect_s3(your_s3_key, your_s3_key_secret)
b = c.get_bucket(bucket, validate=False)

#download the file
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png"
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    #upload the file
    k = Key(b)
    k.key = "image1.png"
    k.content_type = r.headers['content-type']
    k.set_contents_from_string(r.content)
```

Answer (score 19):

You could use [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) from the Python standard library.

```
from io import BytesIO
bytesIO = BytesIO()
bytesIO.write('whee')
bytesIO.seek(0)
s3_file.set_contents_from_file(bytesIO)
```

Comment: Or,  with bytesIO as data: s3.upload_fileobj(data,'','')

Comment: @Roy Hyunjin Han  - could you please embelish, I am having trouble translating this advice to complete the goal. I have a post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165498/use-python-io-to-upload-requests-to-s3-bucket-without-saving-file-locally

Comment: I have been using s3.put_object(Body=bytesIO.getvalue(), Bucket='bucket', Key='key') and that has worked great for me.

Answer (score 13):

The [boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/) library's [Key](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key) object has several methods you might be interested in:

- [send_file](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.send_file)
- [set_contents_from_file](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_file)
- [set_contents_from_string](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_string)
- [set_contents_from_stream](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_stream)

For an example of using set_contents_from_string, see [Storing Data](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html#storing-data) section of the boto documentation, pasted here for completeness:

```
>>> from boto.s3.key import Key
>>> k = Key(bucket)
>>> k.key = 'foobar'
>>> k.set_contents_from_string('This is a test of S3')
```

Comment: But how it is possible in **set_contents_from_file**, and it accepts file which stored locally on disk

Comment: @shihon I don't understand your question.

Comment: See i got a file using request like **file = request.file['name']** and then i save it locally **os.save(os.path.join(path,file))**, from there i set s3 key and **set_contents_from_filename(os.path.join(path,file))**, there i need to save file directly on s3 rather than first save it locally and then on s3...

Comment: i get "AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Answer (score 3):

In boto3, there is a simple way to upload a file content, without creating a local file using following code. I have modified JimJty example code for boto3

```
import boto3
from botocore.retries import bucket
import requests
from io import BytesIO
# set the values
aws_access_key_id=""
aws_secret_access_key=""
region_name=""
bucket=""
key=""

session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key, region_name=region_name)
s3_client = session.client('s3')
#download the file
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png"
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == 200:    
    #convert content to bytes, since upload_fileobj requires file like obj
    bytesIO = BytesIO(bytes(r.content))    
    with bytesIO as data:
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(data, bucket, key)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using `boto`. `boto`'s `Bucket.set_contents_from_file()` will accept a `StringIO` object, and any code you have written to write data to a file should be easily adaptable to write to a `StringIO` object. Or if you generate a string, you can use `set_contents_from_string()`.

Comment: I tried in python file = request.file['name'] set_contents_from_file(file.readlines()), but it needs a string so i iterate and get string but it gives me **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tell'**

Comment: That's because you're passing a string, not a `StringIO` object as I suggested...

Comment: Ohh yes, you are correct but in both way StringIO(file) or StringIO(file.readlines()), file uploaded to s3 but couldn't open shows only blank symbol on browser....

Comment: Well, if you have a `file` you can pass that just in, no need to read it in first...

Answer (score 2):

```
def upload_to_s3(url, **kwargs):
    '''
    :param url: url of image which have to upload or resize to upload
    :return: url of image stored on aws s3 bucket
    '''

    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # credentials stored in settings AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, host=AWS_HOST)

        # Connect to bucket and create key
        b = conn.get_bucket(AWS_Bucket_Name)
        k = b.new_key("{folder_name}/{filename}".format(**kwargs))

        k.set_contents_from_string(r.content, replace=True,
                                   headers={'Content-Type': 'application/%s' % (FILE_FORMAT)},
                                   policy='authenticated-read',
                                   reduced_redundancy=True)

        # TODO Change AWS_EXPIRY
        return k.generate_url(expires_in=AWS_EXPIRY, force_http=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a dict object which I wanted to store as a json file on S3, without creating a local file. The below code worked for me:

```
from smart_open import smart_open

with smart_open('s3://access-key:secret-key@bucket-name/file.json', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(json.dumps(dict_object).encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `smart_open` (https://pypi.org/project/smart_open/). I used it exactly for that: writing files directly in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Given that encryption at rest is a much desired data standard now, smart_open does not support this afaik

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is an example of uploading a list of images (NumPy list, OpenCV image objects) directly to S3

> Note: you need to convert image objects to bytes or buffer to bytes while uploading the file that's how you can upload files without corruption error

```
#Consider you have images in the form of a list i.e. img_array
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
res_url = []

for i,img in enumerate(img_array):
        s3_key = "fileName_on_s3.png"
        response = s3.put_object(Body=img.tobytes(), Bucket='bucket_name',Key=s3_key,ACL='public-read',ContentType= 'image/png')
        s3_url = 'https://bucket_name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/'+s3_key
        res_url.append(s3_url)
#res_url is the list of URLs returned from S3 Upload
```

Answer (score -1):

Update for boto3:

```
aws_session = boto3.Session('my_access_key_id', 'my_secret_access_key')
s3 = aws_session.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('my_bucket').put_object(Key='file_name.txt', Body=my_file)
```

Answer (score -2):

I am having a similar issue, was wondering if there was a final answer, because with my code below , the "starwars.json" keeps on saving locally but I just want to push through each looped .json file into S3 and have no file stored locally.

```
for key, value in star_wars_actors.items():

response = requests.get('http:starwarsapi/' + value)



data = response.json()


with open("starwars.json", "w+") as d:
    json.dump(data, d, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)



s3.upload_file('starwars.json', 'test-bucket',
               '%s/%s' % ('test', str(key) + '.json'))
```

Comment: @susanne hi , I am having a similar problem, wondering what you ended up deciding on?