# how to create dummy files directly in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to create some dummy files in S3 bucket for testing purposes. Since these are dummy files it seems like an overkill to create them locally and upload to S3 (few GB of data). I created the files with `truncate` command in linux. Is it possible to create such files directly in S3 or do I need to upload them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12570465/13126651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload them. Since you created the files using a terminal, you can install the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and then use the [aws s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command upload them to S3. If you have created many files or have a deep folder structure, you can use the `--recursive` command to upload all files from the `myDir` to the `myBucket` recursively:

```sh
aws s3 cp myDir s3://mybucket/ --recursive
```