# AWS Object Lambda using PyPDF2 to send back encrypted PDF

Tags: object, aws-lambda, pypdf

My AWS OBJECT Lambda Function gets an unencrypted PDF via the Object Lambda inputS3Url.  I want to use PyPDF2 to convert this to encrypted PDF, and send back via s3.write_get_object_response.  How do I do this?

```
s3_url = object_get_context["inputS3Url"]

url=s3_url


response = requests.get(url)
my_raw_data = response.content
```

[SAVE ENCRYPTED my_raw_data TO VARIABLE so it can returned via S3.write_get_object_response - HOW?]

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.write_get_object_response(
Body= [WHAT WOULD GO HERE?]
RequestRoute=request_route,
RequestToken=request_token)
```

Comment: The value of this process is that it returns a password protected PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs got you! [Encrypting PDFs](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/encryption-decryption.html) and [Streaming Data](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/streaming-data.html) is what you need (at least if I got you right; let me know if you want to achieve something else than getting a password-protected PDF on S3)

Not tested, but something like this

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from io import BytesIO

reader = PdfReader(BytesIO(my_raw_data))
writer = PdfWriter()

# Add all pages to the writer
for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)

# Add a password to the new PDF
writer.encrypt("my-secret-password")

# Save the new PDF to a file
with BytesIO() as bytes_stream:
    writer.write(bytes_stream)
    bytes_stream.seek(0)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.write_get_object_response(
        Body=bytes_stream,
        RequestRoute=request_route,
        RequestToken=request_token
    )
```

Comment: I am getting this error message on the s3.write_get_object_response --- ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: There was a seek(0) missing - I've added it. Besides that, it is essentially https://stackoverflow.com/a/25214403/562769 . Please let me know if adding the seek(0) fixed the issue

Comment: Adding the seek(0) did the trick.  Thank you!