# Convert Pandas Dataframe to Image and Upload Directly to S3 Bucket Without Saving Locally Using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-s3

I'm writing a Python script that I will be running in a AWS Lamba function. The python script will generate a pandas dataframe that I would like to have converted into either a .jpeg or .png. I want this image file written directly to an S3 bucket without having to save it to a folder on my local machine. I've done research on boto3 and have my access keys for AWS to read and write from S3, but I need help with converting a pandas dataframe to an image file that is then directly uploaded to an s3 bucket.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created [an issue](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image/issues/43) on the `dataframe_image` repository asking this question to the library author, and below is my implementation of his suggestion:

```py
import boto3
import dataframe_image as dfi
from io import BytesIO

# create the buffer in which to store the generated image
png_io = BytesIO()

# assuming that your dataframe is stored as `df` variable
df.dfi.export(png_io)

# create the boto3 client and upload the BytesIO directly;
# create your client in whatever way works for you
session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key, region_name=region_name)
s3_client = session.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_fileobj(png_io, 'your_destination_folder/your_destination_file')
```

For more information, check this [TechOverflow post](https://techoverflow.net/2021/03/08/how-to-use-boto3-to-upload-bytesio-to-wasabi-s3-in-python/) and this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69443870/6456163).